# When running sudo make install environment variables are not passed

Tags: sudo, make

I have problems with using `pkg-config` in a `Makefile`, while running in `sudo` mode. I need to have `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` set for pkg-config to find geany.pc file that is held in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`.

If I run:

```
$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

If I run with `sudo`:

```
$ sudo echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

So I try running my Makefile that looks like this:

```
PLUGIN_DIR=`pkg-config --variable=libdir geany`/geany

all: pyflakes.o
    gcc pyflakes.o -o geanypyflakes.so -shared `pkg-config --libs geany`

pyflakes.o: pyflakes.c
    gcc -Wall -c pyflakes.c -fPIC `pkg-config --cflags geany` 

install:
    echo ${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}
    cp geanypyflakes.so ${PLUGIN_DIR} --verbose

clean:
    rm geanypyflakes.so pyflakes.o


sudo make install
```

and I get following ouput:

```
echo 

cp geanypyflakes.so `pkg-config --variable=libdir geany`/geany --verbose
`geanypyflakes.so' -> `/geany'
```

Why suddenly `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is not set? I can run `sudo -E` and then it works, but I would like to understand why it suddenly is not working.

**EDIT**

Running export before didn't help:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH='/usr/local/lib/pkconfig' && sudo make install
echo 

cp geanypyflakes.so `pkg-config --variable=libdir geany`/geany --verbose
`geanypyflakes.so' -> `/geany'
```

Comment: may be you could try this `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH='/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig' && sudo make install`

Comment: It didn't help. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The

```
sudo echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

command is not doing what you expect. The shell variable is expanded on the commandline before sudo is run. Try using single quotes around $PKG_CONFIG_PATH to stop the expansion on the sudo commandline and you will stop the shell expansion before sudo runs

```
richm@royalcounty:~$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=hello
richm@royalcounty:~$ sudo echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
hello
richm@royalcounty:~$ sudo echo '$PKG_CONFIG_PATH'
$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

In actual fact your original command is wrong because the echo inside sudo will do no variable expansion. You can force that by running the shell explicitly

```
richm@royalcounty:~$ sudo -E echo '$PKG_CONFIG_PATH'
$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
richm@royalcounty:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH'

richm@royalcounty:~$ sudo -E sh -c 'echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH'
hello
```

That demonstrates why your `sudo make install` does not work without the `-E` argument to `sudo`

Comment: The short version of this is "use `sudo -E make install` instead".

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question of why make install environment variables are not passed...

By default sudo cleans out the environment before it executes your command. This is a security feature to stop bad guys influencing the operation of commands that are allowed via sudo.

You can specify the `-E` flag to preserve the environment but you might need to tweak the contents of your sudoers file to give yourself permission.

From `man sudoers`

```
   -E          The -E (preserve environment) option will override the
               env_reset option in sudoers(5)).  It is only available when
               either the matching command has the SETENV tag or the
               setenv option is set in sudoers(5).
```